# Incompatible Types, Object Oriented Programming, Humans with Pets that can be 2 types

Tags: java, oop, types, extends, bluej

I'm writing a few classes: Humans, Pets and Dogs and Cats which extends Pets. When I call the makePetMakeNoise() method in Humans, it should go to the makeNoise() method in Pets and return that. For feedPet(), it should do the same thing but the Cat and Dog method for eat() will be different. Right now, I am getting the error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int... when I try to call makeNoise() from the Pets class. Please help me understand what is wrong.

```
public class Humans {

    String name;
    Pets pet;
    int popcount;

    public Humans(String hname, Pets hpet) {
        name = hname;
        pet = hpet;
    }

    public int populationCount() {
        return popcount;
    }

    public int makePetMakeNoise() {
        int randnum = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        return pet.makeNoise(randnum);
    }

    public void feedPet() {
        pet.eat();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Pets {

    String name;
    String noise;
    boolean canMakeNoise;

    public Pets(String pname, String pnoise, boolean pcanmakenoise) {
        name = pname;
        noise = pnoise;
        pcanmakenoise = canMakeNoise;
    }

    public void makeNoise(int number) {
        if (canMakeNoise != false) {
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                System.out.println(noise + name);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " *remains silent*");
        }
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println(name + " is eating...");
    }

    class Dog extends Pets {

        public Dog(String pname, String pnoise, boolean pcanmakenoise) {
            super(pname, pnoise, pcanmakenoise);
        }

        @Override
        public void eat() {
            System.out.println(name + " is eating...");
        }
    }

    class Cat extends Pets {

        public Cat(String pname, String pnoise, boolean pcanmakenoise) {
            super(pname, pnoise, pcanmakenoise);
        }

        @Override
        public void eat() {
            super.eat();
            System.out.println("I'm still hungry, meow");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hpet.makeNoise returns void, but you return an int in Humans

Comment: `return hpet.makeNoise(randnum);` and `public void makeNoise(int number)`

Comment: i didn't change public int makePetMakeNoise() to public void makePetMakeNoise() ; or return hpet.makeNoise(randnum); to  pet.makeNoise(randnum);  when i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Your `makeNoise` method in class `Pets` returns `void`, but when you call it in class `Humans`, you want to return what value you get from it. Since `makeNoise` doesn't return anything, the statement int class `Humans` will return `void`, but the method is defined as returning an `int`.

```
public int makePetMakeNoise(){}
```

change `int` to `void`, and remove `return` in the same method: `makePetMakeNoise()`

Answer (score 0):

change definition of `Human class` to the following

```
import java.util.*;

public class Humans 
{

    String name;     
    Pets pet;    
    int popcount;

public Humans(String hname, Pets hpet)
{
    name = hname;
    pet = hpet;
}

public int populationCount()
{
    return popcount;
}

public void makePetMakeNoise()
{
    int randnum = (int)(Math.random() *10);
    pet.makeNoise(randnum);
}

public void feedPet()
{
    pet.eat();
}
}
```

because the method `makeNoise(int number)` from `Pets class` is `void` type.

Answer (score 0):

Change makePetMakeNoise method is Humans class as below:

```
public void makePetMakeNoise() {
    int randnum = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    pet.makeNoise(randnum); 
}
```